# intents.json vs training w/ text file in GPT2 for training a chatbot

Tags: json, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Forgive me 'cause I'm fairly new to AI and NN stuff. I'm trying to create a chatbot to have conversations with my friends in our discord channel.

I know that an intents.json file can help the chatbot know the intent of the user's message, then reply with an appropriate response, but it seems very static (i.e. you have a tag like 'greetings' then you have maybe 5-6 written responses ready to go such as "Hi", "hey", "hello there", etc). I'm wanting my chatbot to be able to have dynamic responses (based on what the conversation is so far).

I've fiddled with Max Woolf's Google Colaboratory for GPT2 (https://colab.research.google.com/github/sarthakmalik/GPT2.Training.Google.Colaboratory/blob/master/Train_a_GPT_2_Text_Generating_Model_w_GPU.ipynb) and have used simple text files to train a model.

I'm confused on the difference between using an intents.json file to train an AI model vs. using a regular text file in GPT2 to train the model. Where would you use one vs the other or are they accomplishing the same thing? I hope this makes sense. Any help or clarification would be appreciated as well as resources to read up on stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to use a pre-trained model like dialo-gpt and train it on your own large text data that you can find by dumping Wikipedia text or you can learn about transformer architecture and create your own by scratch using pytorch or tensorFlow

Btw i use pytorch for simplicity. you can use whatever you like.
then you can make a model that is not dependent on pre built anwsers